# How to use $geoNear in mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I am trying to display distance between two coordinates. Below query executes and gives result as expected

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear: "distances",
             near: [ 83.307974, 17.716456],
             spherical: true
           }  );
```

I would like to execute this query from nodejs script. I am using mongoose.
I tried aggregate function yet i failed to obtain the result. Can someone guide me in correct path!

I tried this:

```
 db.getCollection('distances').aggregate([
  { 
        "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
                 "type": "Point",
                 "locc": [83.307974, 17.716456]
             },
             "distanceField": "distance",

             "spherical": true

         }
    }
]);
```

**References:**

[geoNear Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255525/how-to-use-geonear-in-nodejs)
[geoNeam MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing "locc" to "coordinates" and also ensure you have created either a 2d or 2dsphere index for the collection that contains the coordinates.

```
db.getCollection('distances').aggregate([
  { 
        "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
                 "type": "Point",
                 "coordinates": [83.307974, 17.716456]
             },
             "distanceField": "distance",

             "spherical": true

         }
    }
]);
```